# regex match html element with html children

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I wasn't sure how to phrase this question.

Basically I have this php code:

```
$new_html = preg_replace('!<div.*?id="spotlight".*?>.*?</div>!is', '', $html);
```

I want this to change html code from this (example, not actual html):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="spotlight">
        <!-- empty -->
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- lots of content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <!-- lots of content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the php code will do this successfully, because the regex is looking for:

```
<div{anything}id="spotlight"{anything}>{anything}</div>
```

**However**

if the div id="spotlight" contains a child div like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="spotlight">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- lots of content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

then the regex will match the end div tag of the child div!

How do i prevent this? How to i tell regex to ignore the closing div if another div was opened?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have control in the code? If so just edit it! If not you cannot be writing PHP to process it.

Comment: Using regex is not the best way to do this. You should be using a Dom parser like [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). It will make your life easier and your code will be easier to maintain / extend.

Comment: Theres no way i can edit the code directly. This MUST be done using regex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: You'd have to match an optional child div then

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: Can you afford `preg_replace_callback`?

Comment: If you're actually looking for a regular expression, this should give you some pointers: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/parse_with_regexp.html - but, well, you must really want to eat the pain then.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DOMDocument`:

```
$html = '<div id="container">
    <div id="spotlight">
        <!-- empty -->
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- lots of content -->
    </div>
</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = '//div[@id="spotlight"]';
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach($entries as $one){

    $one->parentNode->removeChild($one);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/Fs8wWYee)

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = preg_replace('/<div[^>]+>\\s+<\/div>/', '', $a);
```