# How can I get all HTML elements from an HTML snippet using regular expressions?

Tags: html, regex

Is there a trick to getting all HTML elements using regular expressions? Take this snippet of HTML, for instance:

```
<div>
<p>test
<span>blub</span></p>
</div>
```

in correct order Like:

```
array(
0=>'<div>
<p>test
<span>blub</span></p>
</div>',

1=>'<p>test
<span>blub</span></p>'

2=>'<span>blub</span>'
)
```

I thought of something with

```
 (<([A-z]+)[^>]*>.*?</\2>)
```

Comment: No. [You cannot parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572)

Comment: How about using an HTML parser? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: [The pony, he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question: [regex match html element with html children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564990/regex-match-html-element-with-html-children)

You can't really parse HTML with regular expressions. Use PHP or some other language to parse your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty

```
<[^>]+>
```

Don't expect this to work when you have string with '>' inside them.